# Phase shift in holographic one-point function

Tags: correlation-functions, ads-cft, holographic-principle

I have a simple question about the response of an operator one-point function to an external source $\propto e^{-i\omega t}$ in AdS/CFT.

I consider a real scalar probe of mass $m$ in $AdS_{d+1}$ which is dual to an operator $O$ of dimension $\Delta = d/2 + \nu$ where $\nu = \sqrt{(d/2)^2+m^2}$ and I work in the Euclidean Poincare coordinate system where the metric tensor is given by
$$ds^2 =\frac{1}{z^2}(dz^2+ d\vec x^2)$$
The response of the one-point function to a source $\phi$ is given by (where $k^2: = \vec k \cdot \vec k$ denotes the squared norm of the Euclidean momentum $\vec k \in \mathbb{R}^d$)

$$
\langle O_{\vec{k}} \rangle  \propto (k^2)^\nu \log (k^2) \phi_{\vec{k}} \quad \quad \textrm{if} \quad \quad \nu \in \mathbb{Z} 
$$

or

$$
\langle O_{\vec{k}} \rangle  \propto (k^2)^\nu\phi_{\vec{k}} \quad \quad \textrm{if} \quad \quad \nu \not\in \mathbb{Z} 
$$

In order to get the response to a spatially independent source $\propto e^{-i \omega t}$ we should consider the imaginary Euclidean momentum $\vec k = (i \omega, 0, \ldots, 0)$.

Plugging in, we find that for $\nu \not\in\mathbb{Z}$, the non-analytic part of the one-point function is out of phase with the source (because $(k^2)^\nu = (-\omega^2)^{\nu}$ is imaginary for $\nu \not\in\mathbb{Z}$). On the other hand, for $\nu\in\mathbb{Z}$, the non-analytic part of the one-point function oscillates in phase with the source because $\log (k^2) = \log(-\omega^2) = i\pi + \log(\omega^2)$.

What is the physical reason behind this difference in oscillatory behavior for $\nu \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\nu \not\in\mathbb{Z}$?